# Add Fragment overlay on activity's view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new bie in android.

Below is my senerio what i have and what i actually need.

I have one activity where i have declare one custom view which contains a set of button which click event display respective fragments.

This custom view will be appear on top of each fragment.

Now suppose on first button of custom view i am display fragment a fragment which display list-view..
 on click on list-view it show another fragment i.e detail fragment

In detail fragment.. i have one button where i need to show an fragment overlay on main activity ... as on full screen.. how can i achive this?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide simple paint image to explain your layout?

Comment: Something like this,,http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/8682/myimage2.png

Comment: the mention button will be fixed at all fragment

Comment: are you using tablayout? and you want to access your tablayout in both the views?is that what you want?and paste here what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion easiest way lead to this behavior is use Activity Overlay or DialogFragment. Example:

## Activity Overlay

---

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShow);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Activity"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="show"
        android:id="@+id/buttonShow"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

### SecondActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Second Activity"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="TransparentFloatingActivity" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arturszymanski.test" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@style/TransparentFloatingActivity"
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

## DialogFragment

---

### MyDialogFragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyDialogFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FullScreen Fragment"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### MyDialogFragment.java

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private int margin;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        margin = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        int dialogHeight = MainActivity.displayMetrics.heightPixels - (margin * 2) - MainActivity.StatusBarHeight;
        int dialogWidth = MainActivity.displayMetrics.widthPixels - (margin * 2);
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
    public static int StatusBarHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        StatusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShow);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
            }
        });
    }
    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Other Files

Other files are the same as in example above.

Comment: Hii.. thanks for your efforts.. really appriciated...but dear i do not want second activity as i just do all with fragment only..

Comment: and the fragment portion is fixed as i say that i have a main activity which contain one layout with set of button and which will be visible to all my fragment... now on one of my fragment will need to display over the activty

Comment: @user5457212 You have few fragments already nested inside your activity layout. Now you want to take one of them remove from layout  and make it full screen? Or maybe create new one floating over layout?

Comment: @user5457212 I have added new solution using DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

If i follow your question than, You should use a RelativeLayout as overlay in main activity's layout. and set visibility according to your need.

**layout_activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout>
// your toolbar
// You fragment container
// your main layout goes here

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/overlay"
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
<LinearLayout id = "@+id/container">
<ToolBar id ="@+id/toolbar>
</ToolBar>
<FrameLayout id ="@+id/main_containt"/>
</LinearLayout>
getSupportFragmentManager().add(new Fragment(),R.id.container).commit();
```

use container as the container of `fragment`;